# Is this a bug in HorizontalScrollView's onRequestFocusInDescendants method?

Tags: android, android-fragments, focus, horizontalscrollview

I am developping a project in TV platform, I use `HorizontalScrollView` in layout.Due to the platform, which view is focused is very important.

I think I am faced with some bugs in `HorizontalScrollView`. First, I will explain what kind of bug:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Menu                      ||  Content                                               |
| This is a ListView        ||  This is a FrameLayout which will be replace           |
|                           ||  with Fragment dynamicly if content is clicked.        |
| This view can be          ||                                                        |
| hided with                ||                                                        |
| smoothScrollTo method     ||                                                        |
|                           ||                                                        |
| Menu1                     ||  Content1                                              |
| Menu2                     ||  Content2                                              |
| Menu3                     ||  Content3                                              |
|                           ||  Content4                                              |
|                           ||  Content5                                              |
|                           ||  Content6                                              |
|                           ||  Content7                                              |
|                           ||  Content8                                              |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Menu and Content are both clickable, here is the bug:

when Menu is hided, I click `OK` button on some content(this bug can only be reappeared when some content is focused), the content view will be replaced with a new Fragment, but **the Menu will show automatically**.

I have find the reason why the menu will show automatically:

`onRequestFocusInDescendants(int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect)` have code like this:

```
final View nextFocus = previouslyFocusedRect == null ? FocusFinder.getInstance().findNextFocus(this, null, direction) : FocusFinder.getInstance().findNextFocusFromRect(this, previouslyFocusedRect, direction);
```

`FocusFinder.getInstance().findNextFocus(this, null, direction)` return the `Menu` view, so in the end of this method will `requestFocus` the menu view.

I am not familiar with `FocusFinder`(and the source code is a little bit difficult for a new android coder), I want to know why the `findNextFocus` will return the menu view.